Msg 5161: An unexpected file id was encountered after server restore
I'm aware of a similar question asked here, but it was never answered;
After the Crowdstrike incident, one of my SQL VMs was blessed with a corrupted registry. I fixed the drive via attaching the OS to a different VM as a secondary, then creating a new VM from it;
However, my SQL instance is now in a permanent 'Recovery Pending' state. Any operation I try to do against it gives me the following errors;
Msg 5161, Level 16, State 1, Line 31
An unexpected file id was encountered. File id 3 was expected but 4 was read from "E:\MSSQL\Data\TBStg_365DayPartition.ndf". Verify that files are mapped correctly in sys.master_files. ALTER DATABASE can be used to correct the mappings.
Msg 5161, Level 16, State 1, Line 31
An unexpected file id was encountered. File id 4 was expected but 3 was read from "E:\MSSQL\DATA\TBStg_30DayPartition.ndf". Verify that files are mapped correctly in sys.master_files. ALTER DATABASE can be used to correct the mappings.
Msg 5161, Level 16, State 1, Line 31
An unexpected file id was encountered. File id 7 was expected but 8 was read from "E:\MSSQL\DATA\TBStg_7DayPartition.ndf". Verify that files are mapped correctly in sys.master_files. ALTER DATABASE can be used to correct the mappings.

I have tried logging in as a single users, entering emergency mode, remapping, executing from the command line, etc? I can't even detach the database as every operation gives me this error. I have checked thoroughly that the files exist, including a second set of eyes. I don't know how to get the server up and running.
Note, the database and log files were initially wrong as well, but remapping those caused their respective error to disappear.
